# When promise chain is badly coded, code works

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird

I am having a bit of a problem understanding why this works:

```
var userId;
var token;
var result = {};
var merchantId;
userCtrl.loginUser(req.body.email, req.body.password).then(function(data) {
            if (data.length == 1) {
                userId = data[0].user_id;
                return merchantCtrl.isMerchant(userId);
            } else {
                res.json({
                    result: 2
                });
            }
        }).then(function(data) {
            //If its merchant
            if (data.length === 1) {
                merchantId = data[0].merchant_id;
                token = tokenUtil.createTokenMerchant(merchantId, userId);
                result.token = token;
                getFullUser(userId).then(function(userObject) {
                    result.user = userObject;
                    result.user.user_id = userId;
                    merchantCtrl.getMerchant(merchantId)
                        .then(function(data) {
                            result.merchant = data[0];
                            res.json(result);
                        });
                });
            } else {
                token = tokenUtil.createTokenUser(userId);
                result.token = token;
                return getFullUser(userId);
            }
        }).then(function(userObject) {
            result.user = userObject;
            result.user.user_id = userId;
            res.json(result);
        })
```

So as you can see in this code it is missing the final catch condition and a semicolon. But this compiles fine and the response is accurate.

Now here is the interesting part: getFullUser is a function that using promises fetches all the user info (duh!) and after all promises resolve it returns an Object containing that user.

Note that the getFullUser function does NOT return a promise.

Now after seeing this bug I added the final catch and the semicolon:

```
var userId;
        var token;
        var result = {};
        var merchantId;
        userCtrl.loginUser(req.body.email, req.body.password).then(function(data) {
            if (data.length == 1) {
                userId = data[0].user_id;
                return merchantCtrl.isMerchant(userId);
            } else {
                res.json({
                    result: 2
                });
            }
        }).then(function(data) {
            //If its merchant
            if (data.length === 1) {
                merchantId = data[0].merchant_id;
                token = tokenUtil.createTokenMerchant(merchantId, userId);
                result.token = token;
                getFullUser(userId).then(function(userObject) {
                    result.user = userObject;
                    result.user.user_id = userId;
                    merchantCtrl.getMerchant(merchantId)
                        .then(function(data) {
                            result.merchant = data[0];
                            res.json(result);
                        });
                });
            } else {
                token = tokenUtil.createTokenUser(userId);
                result.token = token;
                return getFullUser(userId);
            }
        }).then(function(userObject) {
            result.user = userObject;
            result.user.user_id = userId;
            res.json(result);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("error: " + error.message + "; code: " + error);
            res.status(500).json({
                message: "Error logging in."
            });
        });
```

I get this error when this is run:

```
error: Cannot set property 'user_id' of undefined; code: TypeError: Cannot set property 'user_id' of undefined
```

This indicates when assigning the user_id to result.user, user is undefined. 
That means since the return on the getFullUser is async the code is not waiting for its return and just uses undefined.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

I have already changed the code to a better solution but I am wondering why this happens.

Comment: Javascript will auto add the final semicolon. You also don't "need" a catch. `getFullUser` definitely thinks it's a promise or else the `.then()` would return an error. Are you sure something inside `getFullUser` isn't a promise?

Comment: GetFullUser does use promises inside but returns a simple object after they resolve and return the data needed. Why adding a catch makes the code not wait for the getFullUser function?

Answer (score 0):

1. **catch()** in bottom of chain - is not required, but highly recommended. Without catch - you can lost errors
2. in **then()** block with

   getFullUser(userId).then(function(userObject) ...

you call promise, but did not return result (did not waiting for result), that's why on next step, you receive 'undefined' as param in **next** block

set

```
return getFullUser(userId).then(function(userObject)
```